# Auto-Update main question page

Tags: feature-request, live-refresh, homepage

I sometimes find while I'm working that I leave the SO question page open (or a specific tag). I do this until an interesting question pops up etc.

Would it be possible (and useful to the community) to utilise the same feature that is used when answering a question and someone else answers on this screen?

The feature I am talking about is the orange bar alert that says "new answers available". I suppose it would work in much the same way that it does on the Twitter feed "x more tweets available"

Comment: As an aside, though I'd not use such auto-update: I think that also would lower the server load. When a user explicitly reloads a page (simply Ctrl-R), many (if not all) browsers also kindly ask the server if cached resources (images, JavaScript) need reloading, using an `If-Modified-Since` header. This is different from reloading the page by clicking the SO logo, or by using a bookmark, or by hitting Return in the location bar. (Note that using things like Firebug or Web Inspector to test might might actually affect the normal behaviour.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, good to have feedback.